# Powershell SQL Merge on output?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have scrubbed together some powershell to scan a directory list the contents and then insert to a MS SQL (2017) table without creating duplicates.

I am unable to to amend the MERGE to delete old/orphaned row in sql based on a compare of the current directory:

```
   Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Web"
function Get-FriendlySize {
    param($Bytes)
    $sizes='Bytes,KB,MB,GB,TB,PB,EB,ZB' -split ','
    for($i=0; ($Bytes -ge 1kb) -and 
        ($i -lt $sizes.Count); $i++) {$Bytes/=1kb}
    $N=2; if($i -eq 0) {$N=0}
    "{0:N$($N)} {1}" -f $Bytes, $sizes[$i]
}
 #Declare Servername
$sqlServer='localhost'
#Invoke-sqlcmd Connection string parameters
$params = @{'server'='localhost';'Database'='kentico'}

#Fucntion to manipulate the data
Function writeDiskInfo
{
param ($FileName, $FileTitle, $FileDescription,$FileExtension,$FileMimeType,$FilePath,$FileSize,$FileImageWidth,$FileImageHeight,$FileGUID,$FileLibraryID,$FileSiteID,$FileCreatedByUserID,$FileCreatedWhen,$FileModifiedByUserID, $FileModifiedWhen,$FileCustomData,$FileDate)
# Data preparation for loading data into SQL table 
$InsertResults = @"

Merge dbo.Media_File AS T

USING (SELECT  FileName = '$FileName') AS S 
ON S.FileName = T.FileName

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
INSERT  (FileName,FileTitle,FileDescription,FileExtension,FileMimeType,FilePath,FileSize,FileImageWidth,FileImageHeight,FileGUID,FileLibraryID,FileSiteID,FileCreatedByUserID,FileCreatedWhen,FileModifiedByUserID,FileModifiedWhen,FileCustomData,FileDate)
VALUES ('$FileName','$FileTitle','$FileDescription','$FileExtension','$FileMimeType','$FilePath','$FileSize','$FileImageWidth','$FileImageHeight', '$FileGUID','$FileLibraryID','$FileSiteID','$FileCreatedByUserID','$FileCreatedWhen','$FileModifiedByUserID', '$FileModifiedWhen','$FileCustomData',CAST('$FileDate' AS datetime))

**This is where I get stuck**
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND   
   (SELECT  FileName = '$FileName')  = T.FileName THEN
        DELETE;




"@      
#call the invoke-sqlcmdlet to execute the quer'
         Invoke-sqlcmd @params -Query $InsertResults
}

#Query WMI query to store the result in a varaible
$dp = (get-childitem  -Path   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Kentico11\CMS\t\media\test\ -Recurse -file  |Select-Object -property @{Label='FileName';Expression={$_.baseName}},@{Label='FileTitle';Expression={$_.baseName}},@{N='FileDescription';E={"bob"}},@{Label='FileExtension';Expression={$_.Extension }},@{N='FileMimeType';E={[System.Web.MimeMapping]::GetMimeMapping("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Kentico11\CMS\Enert\media\test\Compliance Analysis 2018-13-04.pdf")}},@{Label='FilePath';Expression= {($_.fullname.remove( 0, 58).replace( '\' ,'/'))}},@{N='FileSize';E={'1234'}},@{N='FileImageWidth';E={(Null)}},@{N='FileImageHeight';E={(Null)}},@{N='FileGUID';E={[guid]::newguid()}},@{N='FileLibraryID';E={("15")}},@{N='FileSiteID';E={("3")}},@{N='FileCreatedByUserID';E={("53")}},@{Label='FileCreatedWhen';Expression={$_.creationtime}},@{N='FileModifiedByUserID';E={("53")}}, @{Label='FileModifiedWhen';Expression={$_.creationtime}},@{N='FileCustomData';E={(Null)}},@{Label='FileDate';Expression={($_.baseName.Substring($_.basename.Length -13, 13))}}) 

#Loop through array
foreach ($item in $dp)
{
#Call the function to transform the data and prepare the data for insertion
writeDiskInfo $item.FileName $item.FileTitle $item.FileDescription $item.FileExtension $item.FileMimeType $item.FilePath $item.FileSize $item.FileImageWidth $item.FileImageHeight $item.FileGUID  $item.FileLibraryID $item.FileSiteID  $item.FileCreatedByUserID $item.FileCreatedWhen $item.FileModifiedByUserID $item.FileModifiedWhen $item.FileCustomData $item.FileDate  
}


  Invoke-Sqlcmd @params -Query "SELECT  * FROM Media_File" | format-table -AutoSize
```

Comment: You want to delete from dbo.Media_Type when the file doesn't exist on disk, right? If so, then `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE`. There's no need for the `AND (SELECT  FileName = '$FileName')  = T.FileName` since you already checked in your `MERGE-USING` statement.

Comment: Yes I want to  delete rows in dbo.media_file that does not exist in on disk. WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE deletes all entries from the dbo.media_file table

Comment: I get it now. You are calling writeDiskInfo once per file. Because of that, you can't do what you want this way because if the current file doesn't exist in the Media_Types then ALL records will be deleted . You would need to do something like load all disk file info into a staging table and then do the merge. If you want speed, you can build out a flat file and use `BULK INSERT` to load the staging table (or temp table).